# How do I know which client is transferring data to my server?

Tags: python, sockets

I've been digging around for a while and I've come away with good understanding, nothing that quite gets to what I'm trying to do:

I need a server that multiple clients connect to.  Every once in a while a client will query the server for a new set of numbers to work on (Distributed computing, essentially), which the server then sends back to the client that queried.

How can I tell which client queried the server so I can respond back to it?

I'm fairly new to Python, and the select() function itself is a bit confusing.  I am capable of accepting new connections, and getting input, but the server doesn't seem to know which client is talking to it (Or possibly my debugging text is not correct, and it does know??).

Anyways, here's the code for the server:

```
while running:
    #select returns 3 subsets of the input containing sockets that have stuff to be read, empty buffer for writing, or an error
    readers, writers, error = select.select(input, output, errors)
    for s in readers:
        if s == serversocket:
            #readable server socket is ready for connection
            connection, client_addr = s.accept()
            print >> sys.stderr, 'new connection from', client_addr
            connection.setblocking(0)
            #clients.append([client_addr, performance])
            input.append(connection)
            output.append(connection)
        else:
            #readable socket, not ready for new connection
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print >> sys.stderr, "readable socket, not ready for new connection"
            if data:
                #the socket actually has data (put Compute process data into list)
                print >> sys.stderr, "Data received"
                substring = data[0:data.find("sss")];
                print >> sys.stderr, 'received %s from %s' % (substring, client_addr)
                if substring == "-get":
                    print >> sys.stderr, 'received -get command'
                    determinerange()
                    print >> sys.stderr, 'sending range of %d to %d', currentlow, currenthigh
                    temp = currentlow+"\0"
                    connection.send(currentlow)
                    temp = currenthigh+"\0"
                    connection.send(currenthigh)
                elif substring == "-k":
                    print >> sys.stderr, 'received -k, stopping'
```

Essentially it receives some sort of command, and turns around and sends the data it needs.  In case you were wondering, this server has to talk to a C program that I also am writing, which actually does the calculations.  That's why I'm appending the newline "\0" character. If it receives -k from any of the clients, it needs to stop every client and exit.

Note: I can only use the standard python library.  I can't get any of the extra things that would make things easier :)

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: Usually something like this is within a larger framework. The establishment of a socket connection would be one step, then it would routed to some other running process or module that would handle authentication based on some predefined protocol. The python networking objects here are managing some of the TCP information from you. For instance the client_addr that is returned from accept() will give you the senders IP.

Comment: Yeah.  And I can use that to return data to that client, but only if no other connections happen prior to me sending data to that client.  If a new connection comes in, it sets the client_addr as the newest connected client.  I'm wondering how you send data back to a client that sent you data without knowing client_addr for that person.  EJP said that you simply send it back to the same socket, so does that mean that the select also contains the client information when I receive data?  When I send data it will automatically select the one that I had just received from?

Comment: The reference you have to the socket object is a connection with a unique remote server. You can basically send or receive any bytes you want, assuming both ends agree on what to do with it.
[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm)

Comment: This might help, also: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the lines:

```
                connection.send(currentlow)
                ...
                connection.send(currenthigh)
```

by:

```
                s.send(currentlow)
                ...
                s.send(currenthigh)
```

That will send the message to the current client from whom you've received some data, instead of the client stored in the variable connection.

Comment: Oho! I see!  Very cool.  Select for some reason is very confusing for me.

Comment: Alright well, now i'm getting a mysterious broken pipe.  I assume it's gotta be in the C program.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that now after sending the data from the server, my C program gets it just fine, but then the script wants to close the connection instead of listening for more queries.  Why is this?

Comment: The connection shouldn't be closed, that's strange! Without looking to the rest of your code, I can't give an answer to your 2nd problem.

Comment: Ah yes, well the only thing after that portion is an else statement that follows the if data: segment which closes connections that return no data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know which client. The socket is the client, to all intents and purposes. Just send the response via the same socket you received the request from.

Comment: What's to prevent the server from sending the message to all connected clients?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There's nothing to prevent *you* from *writing the code that way,* if you so choose, but the server won't send anything anywhere unless you write some code, and the code I am suggesting you write sends to the client the request came from.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, I apparently fundamentally misunderstood how the Select() worked.  I had thought it was creating lists of connected clients, and I had to somehow specify which one to send data to.

Comment: @FeralShadow With respect, I suggest you stop guessing and start reading some documentation. select() is used to tell you which sockets are ready to read: you process those, reading each one and sending the response back down the same socket.

Comment: Sure, I suppose the only reason I was confused was that I only have one socket.

Comment: @FeralShadow If you only have one socket you can only have one client so your question cannot possibly arise. If you have more than one client you must have more than one socket, each one returned by an accept() call. I suggest you keep reading.

Comment: Ahh ok. And select chooses the socket that has activity on it to be referenced by the rest of the calls.

Comment: @FeralShadow No, it does what I said above: selects *all* the sockets that are ready for reading. Then you iterate over them in your `for s : readers` loop. So at any given time the socket you are dealing with is `s`. Keep reading.